# Glassfish server can not run html page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3

My ubuntu crashed and I started to setup all the development environment again.I imported my project from github. Adjusted project facets from Eclipse project properties to Dynamic Web module 3.0, Glassfish web extensions 3.1, Java, Javascript and JPA 2.0. My glassfish server 3.1 is started and running.localhost:8080 shows the server is running. My project is also added to server configuration. When I right click one of html pages and select run as -> run on server nothing happens. No error message or non started html page in the browser.
What could be the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new dynamic web project with same project facet details and noticed glassfish-web.xml file under web content -> web-inf 
In my previous project I had sun-web.xml and web.xml files and after copying the glassfish-web.xml file under same folder html page started to opened with browser.